# How to measure response time of a POST reply from a server which is running a CGI script

Tags: python, linux, apache, ubuntu, cgi

I am trying to measure the response time of a very simple service running in Apache in an Ubuntu VM. The service consists of an HTML form which will originate a POST request to be answered using a CGI script. The CGI script merely takes 2 integers to be input in the form, sums them, and returns a string with the result.

Accessing the VM through a browser, when the form button is clicked the result is displayed in a new tab. The reply time can be easily obtained using Wireshark, however, what I want to do is to create a script that will send a batch of requests and obtain an average value within a certain interval of confidence. I am trying to make the script in Python using the requests library.

**My problem is the following: when I use the post method in the measuring script I do not get the reply but the initial webpage that contains the form.** Even though the post method has the allow_redirects option set to true by default. So I am not measuring the response time of my service but the response time of just getting the form. What can I do to resolve this?

**I present a minimum reproducible example below**, just follow the steps.

1 - Create the master_script.sh file with the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#install apache2 and python2.x in Debian based VM
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 python

#setting up virtual hosts
sudo mkdir /var/www/simple_server
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/simple_server
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/simple_server

#copy webpage
cp index.html /var/www/simple_server

#copy virtual host conf file and enable it, disable default
sudo cp simple_server.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo a2ensite simple_server.conf
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf

#copy cgi python script
sudo mkdir /var/www/simple_server/scripts
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/simple_server/scripts
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/simple_server/scripts
sudo cp post_reply.py /var/www/simple_server/scripts
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/simple_server/scripts/post_reply.py
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/simple_server/scripts/post_reply.py

#enable cgi
sudo a2enmod cgi
```

2 - Create the simple_server.conf file with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName simple_server
    ServerAlias simple_server
    DocumentRoot /var/www/simple_server
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

3 - Create the index.html file with the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to Simple CGI Server!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Simple CGI Server</h1>
    <h2>Input 2 numbers to be added</h2>
    <form action="scripts/post_reply.py" method="post" target="_blank">
         Operand 1: <input type="text" name="operand1"><br>
         Operand 2: <input type="text" name="operand2"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

4 - Create the post_reply.py file with the following:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb
# Create instance of FieldStorage
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
#TEST
if "operand1" not in form or "operand2" not in form:
    print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
    print "<html>"
    print "<head>"
    print "<title>CGI</title>"
    print "</head>"
    print "<body>"
    print "<h1>Error</h1>"
    print "There is some problem with post..."
    print "</body>"
    print "</html>"
else:
# Get data from fields
    op1 = int(form.getvalue('operand1'))
    op2 = int(form.getvalue('operand2'))
    sum = op1 + op2
    print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
    print "<html>"
    print "<head>"
    print "<title>CGI</title>"
    print "</head>"
    print "<body>"
    print "<h2>The numbers add to %d</h2>" % sum
    print "</body>"
    print "</html>"
```

5 - Put the 4 files in the same directory and run the master script.

6 - Add the following to apache2.conf in /etc/apache2:

```
<Directory /var/www/simple_server/scripts>
        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

7 - Restart apache

```sh
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

8 - The server is now operational - test it by entering the IP of the VM in your browser

9 - Finally, access the server using the measuring script - test.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import requests

url = 'http://{THE-VM'S-IP-GOES-IN-HERE}'
myobj = {'operand1': 7, 'operand2': 5}

initial_time = time.clock()
x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
final_time = time.clock() - initial_time

print(x.text)
print(final_time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by simply using the URL of the CGI script instead of the URL of the index page.

On the measuring script (step 9) change:

```py
url = 'http://{THE-VM'S-IP-GOES-IN-HERE}'
```

To:

```py
url = 'http://{THE-VM'S-IP-GOES-IN-HERE}/scripts/post_reply.py'
```